# Exporting Indesign to PDF to Powerpoint

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-acrobat, microsoft-powerpoint, file-conversion

Anyone know the best practice to export a Indesign file into Powerpoint? I have tried multiple plug in converters and am still finding the best way is to export to PDF, then PDF to Powerpoint.

However, sometimes files transfer smoothly and other times the formatting is extremely warped. Is there any tricks to help here? I know Powerpoint doesn't work well with transparencies, any ways to flatten the file or work around this?

For context, the end goal is to create a template that can be used in Powerpoint by a non-designer. I know the best way to do it would be creating directly in Powerpoint, but unfortunately that is not an option.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you use the same document dimension? Otherwise your PDF template won’t match with the PowerPoint master document. PowerPoint uses Pixel.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the plugin ID2Office 2019 from Recosoft

I had to do this a couple of times and I found the best was to just manually recreate the layout in powerpoint with each part of the layout being its own asset.

Answer (score 1):

The **best practice** is to do the layout in the native program. Period, no workaround.

> but unfortunately that is not an option.

I find really difficult to understand why that is not an option. You have at least 4 free ones.

If you have not a Microsoft license you can use **[Libre Office](https://www.libreoffice.org/)**, which compatibility is a decent one for a basic layout. You can use **Google Docs**, **[Open Office](https://www.openoffice.org)** or **[WPS presentation](https://www.wps.com/presentation)**.
You can use a **[free version online of PowerPoint](https://www.office.com/launch/powerpoint)**.

After doing a basic layout, if there are some specific features that must be done in Powerpoint itself transitions or animations perhaps you can go renting a computer for 1 hour at some local internet cafe, and deliver the proper product to the client.